# Translate This pop up covers content

Tags: javascript, jquery, translate

I am using the [Translate This](http://www.translateth.is/docs) service for translation on my site.  Everything works great but for one thing. When you translate the site a bar drops down that says

> Page Finished Translating. Translated by the 
>   TranslateThis Button  |  Undo Translation >

That is also fine but the issue is that the bar covers up content on my site. Is there a way to change the script in some form that will push the content down instead of covering it up? I do not see a way to do this in the settings of translate this but I was wondering if someone might help me figure out how to hard code that in there. I do not know enough about javascript to do this myself.

Thanks for any and all help!

[Here](http://screencast.com/t/foOjOje5FdH) is a short video to show what I mean by content being covered up.

Here is the Translate This code used on my site:

```
<!-- Begin TranslateThis Button -->
<div id="translate-this"><a href="http://translateth.is/" 
class="translate-this-button">Translate</a></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://x.translateth.is/translate-this.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
TranslateThis({
  GA : true,
  doneText : 'Page Finished Translating. Translated by the',
  undoText : 'Undo Translation »', 
  undoLength : 15000, 
  fromLang : 'en',
  ddLangs : [ 
'es',
'fr',
'en',
'ar',
'zh-CN',
'ko',
'it',
'cs',
'iw',
'de',
'pt-PT',
'ru',
'ja',
'vi',
'el',
'hi',
'nl',
'tr'
   ],
    btnImg : '/images/skin/translate-button.png',
    btnWidth : 120,
    btnHeight : 18,
});
</script>
<!-- End TranslateThis Button -->
```

Thanks for any help anyone can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popup is a dynamically created div with class `ttb-undo`.  It is absolutely positioned by a CSS file which is included by the TranslateThis script.  The easiest solution is to just hide the bar entirely:

```
.ttb-undo {
   display: none;
}
```

You could also try changing its position and top values in a CSS sheet, but since it's shrunk programmatically, I'm not sure what kind of jittering you might get.  When I manually deleted the `top: 0` rule and added a `bottom: 0` in Firebug, the thing danced as it was shrinking.

Comment: It goes away after 15 seconds (I can control the time) I was wanting it to stay up so the user can easily undo the translation but not have it cover content. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, you can always style the div to be partially opaque as a low work solution.  If you want to go all out, there is an onComplete callback which the TranslateThis API provides that you can hook.  So you can hide the undo bar as shown above, then use that hook to create a box on your page which provides the same functionality, but which you can ensure doesn't obscure any of your content.